# IronPython Excel RTDServer

Tags: python, excel, ironpython, ironpython-studio, rtd

How do you build a Excel RTDServer in Python/IronPython. (IE I want to implement the IRTDServer interface in Python/IronPython. So I can push data into Excel in real time from Python/IronPython)

I have looked all over the place but the only examples that I'm able to find are in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pyrtd` that implements an Excel RTD Server.

You can find the code on [Google Code page of the project](http://code.google.com/p/pyrtd/)

Comment: I would like to build the server in Python/IronPython. From reading the page that you linked pyrtd is a client of the server. "pyrtd implements a Python RTD client that can receive real-time data from any RTD component. "

Comment: @Josh: sorry, i misread your question. Maybe you could try or adapt this code: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Python/Windows/pyExcelerator/pywin32-214/com/win32com/demos/excelRTDServer.py.htm (i never tried it before though)

Comment: No problem. I just found that article as well and was thinking the same thing.